# Artifacts when recycling Android view objects

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-view, object-pooling

I am introducing view object recycling into my Android app to help performance.  It does help with that.  But when a new screen appears, I am seeing brief artifacts which I assume are related to the prior state of the views.  The artifacts take the form of a rectangular region of some color that should not be there.  The app adjusts itself to the correct state very quickly, but it's still annoying.  I am wondering if there is a way to prevent this.  What I am currently doing is removing the old view from the hierarchy and un-setting its event handlers.  Obviously, that is not enough.  LayoutParams typically relate a view to its parent; perhaps I need to be somehow "un-laying-out" the view when removing it?  But I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If your performance issues lay in a ListView, you can use RecyclerView instead to help that: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html.

Besides that, how exactly are you recycling and what type of Views do you use?

Comment: Not just in ListViews.  It is a custom subclass of FrameLayout that syncs its properties to a Model object.

Comment: If you use a framelayout, maybe Cards (same link as above) could work for you. They are inserted as rows into the RecyclerView.